# Can't query on wal data in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I'm fairly new to Influxdb. Recently I have installed InfluxeDB v1.0. My problem is I can write data into arbitrary DB, but I can't query on inserted data until one hour.

It's probably wal-flush-interval time, but I read in docs that queries execute on both wal and persist data.

Can anyone tell where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The silly problem was that my machine time was 1 hour ahead of InfluxeDB server time, and seemingly queries in InfluxDB run with implicit where clause of  `time < now()`, and because of that I could query with 1 hour delay.